# How to style an asp.net mvc button two different ways using span?

Tags: html, css

I have button like so:

```
<button type="submit" name="button1" value="1" style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; font-size: 20px;">Line 1 <br /><span class="blue">line 2</span></button>
```

and my css:

```
.blue { color: blue;}
```

But its not applying the second css style, any ideas, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

May be *typo*! The `CSS` class name is `"blue"` not a `"bluetext".`

Comment: no, I typed in here wrong.  They match and I am still not getting it.

Comment: well, its clearly working at jsfiddle, but its not in my .cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

I guess some other style definitions are overriding it. Ttry to use the `!important`  forcefull use this color over other definitions

```
.blue { color: blue !important;}
```